# Flutter create special table with button

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a small task, however, I've been trying to reproduce this in Flutter for 2 days, but can't manage it, unfortunately. Would ask you to help me a little. It should be a table with buttons where you can book as a customer at a certain time, but if someone has already booked something in between, you can only book up to the date or after, see the video.
And I'm sorry if this is a bit of an unusual question, however, I'm getting desperate
Thank you in advance.

PS: It would be important to mention that the design is not as important as the functionality

[Video](https://www.veed.io/view/e1a2a61b-d9e6-4adc-99e8-a5940b40955f?panel=share)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Table](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) widget and [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) within your Table widget like this :

```dart
    Table(
      border: TableBorder.all(),
      columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
        0: FixedColumnWidth(96),
        1: FixedColumnWidth(96),
        2: FixedColumnWidth(96),
        3: FixedColumnWidth(96),
        4: FixedColumnWidth(96),
      },
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      children: <TableRow>[
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        TableRow(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 64,
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 64,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                ),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 64,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.dangerous,
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 64,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 64,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, I got the design half way, the problem is the functionality, how do I get it to work like it does in video

Comment: You may use a database or an api to store when the thing is booked, and then import it into your Flutter app and use it!

Comment: yes that is clear to me, I get the data from an API but how I program the functionality that is shown in the video is a mystery to me

Comment: Create a dart object, then parse your api response with `jsonDecode`, after that you will have your object with your data and will be able to use it. Reload the state and render the thing you want